# Identity function for phantom types

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

Is it possible to write something like an identity function with phantom types, with the purpose of converting the type?

For example, given the following type definitions

```
data Nucleotide a = A | C | G | T | U
data RNA = RNA
data DNA = DNA
```

I would like to write a conversion function like

```
r2d :: Nucleotide RNA -> Nucleotide DNA
r2d U = T
r2d x = x
```

This does not type-check however, since the single variable `x` cannot have a different type on the opposite sides.

Is it possible to write this without having to enumerate through

```
r2d :: Nucleotide RNA -> Nucleotide DNA
r2d U = T
r2d A = A
r2d C = C
r2d G = G
```

Comment: If you have a new version of ghc, use `cast :: Nucleotide a -> Nucleotide b; cast = coerce`, where `coerce` is from `GHC.Exts`. Otherwise, use `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: @user2407038 You should make that an answer.

Comment: You could also use the [tagged](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.2/docs/Data-Tagged.html) package, which already provides such functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR:
Don't make a datatype where invalid data is possible:
`T :: Nucleotide RNA` is possible, and that's nonsense biologically, so you might get `r2d T` (a runtime crash you could have prevented at compile time).

Note that [Chris Drost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696585/1598537) deserves credit for being a good answer to the technical question as asked.

---

### Problem

I noticed a potential source of crashes in that your function `r2d` is not total - `r2d T` is not defined, and realised that that was because you have no intention of having `T :: Nucleotide RNA` (nor `U :: Nucleotide DNA`). That's a problem because any time you accidentally have (a user-error generated) `r2d T` your whole program will crash.

This is a design flaw in your type. A major point of the type system is to make invalid data impossible, but yet your code allows `T :: Nucleotide RNA` and even `T :: Nucleotide [Bool]`.

### Straightforward solution

Sadly the solution is to make more boring/less slick types where there's a distinction between DNA's C and RNA's C, but you can use a derived `Enum` instance to convert them without all the typing.

```
data DNA = A | C | G | T deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum)
data RNA = A' | C' | G' | U' deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum)

r2d :: RNA -> DNA
r2d = toEnum.fromEnum

d2r :: DNA -> RNA
d2r = toEnum.fromEnum
```

`toEnum.fromEnum :: (Enum a, Enum b) => a -> b` works by converting from the Enum type to `Int` then from `Int` to the other Enum type.

Now `r2d T` is just a type error, so the program won't compile if you allow this, whereas with the phantom type, it'll compile and crash at runtime if the user manages to enter invalid data.

### Must we distinguish between RNA's C and DNA's C?

(No....)

You might feel that it's wrong to differentiate between `C` and `C'` in that they're the same from a Biological/Chemical point of view, and there may be some compromise position where you have a phantom type with constructors `A | C | G | TU` and read user data differently depending on the context:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
data Nucleotide a = A | C | G | TU deriving (Eq,Enum)
data RNA = RNA
data DNA = DNA

instance Show (Nucleotide DNA) where
  show A = "A"
  show C = "C"
  show G = "G"
  show TU = "T"

instance Show (Nucleotide RNA) where
  show A = "A"
  show C = "C"
  show G = "G" 
  show TU = "U"

r2d :: (Nucleotide RNA) -> (Nucleotide DNA)
r2d = toEnum.fromEnum

d2r :: (Nucleotide DNA) -> (Nucleotide RNA)
d2r = toEnum.fromEnum
```

### Slick, but...

Sometimes making a complicated type just increases the number of extensions you need to use when if you could tolerate a few `'`s, you'd have something with fewer potential problems.

It seems to me you'd be better off with my first solution and writing a custom instances for `Show RNA` and `Read RNA` where the user doesn't need to put the `'` on the end of the letter.

### Always avoid runtime errors if you can

Note though, that `read` is never a total function (i.e. a cause of program crashes), and you're better off using `readMay` from the [`safe` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) so that you can recover gracefully and give your user a polite error message and the chance to fix it, rather than crashing, or by writing a parser using Parsec or similar to read in large amounts of complex structured data, where read or readMay are needlessly slow.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I would prefer the second option if I want to write polymorphic functions for `Nucleotide` though, right? A lot of them will be basic string processing functions, so technically I could have them polymorphic with type `[a]` rather than type `[Nucleotide a]`, but it would be nice to have more specific type annotations.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV Do your functions need to use the fact that it's `C` or just that it's a specific one of the four nucleotides? If I relabelled them P,Q,R,S and didn't tell you which way round, would your algorithm be broken, or could it run using those letters and equality?

Comment: So far they are all equality/comparison based, so relabeling and reordering them would not matter at the moment.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV You'd be OK with functions using the type `Eq a => [a]` then, so you don't need Nucleotide at the moment, and if you do later, all the functions that work for `Eq a => [a]` will work for `[Nucleotide a]` anyway, so you won't need to rewrite processing code if that turns up.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it slightly faster with a case statement:

```
r2d :: Nucleotide RNA -> Nucleotide DNA
r2d x = case x of U -> T; A -> A; C -> C; G -> G
```

We also know that these have the same representations, so you can use unsafeCoerce from `Unsafe.Coerce`. They're bringing compiler-inference for this sort of thing to GHC; [read more about coerce here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles).

Comment: By faster, do you mean that case statements are more performant than pattern matching, or simply that they are more concise?

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV Concise - pattern matching desugars to case statements anyway.